# Making use of rendering templates and will_paginate in script/console or a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I want to pre-generate some pages using a rake task. I want to generate pages of all the users (800.000 and 90 users per page so a little bit less then 9000 pages). Save the page on the disk.

Now i make a lot of requests in the rake task to an controller action and get the results with Mechanize and save the page on the disk.

The problem is that i dont want to make so many requests to my server (because it gets timed out) Speed doesnt matter because i have an extra server.I want to generate the pages without doing a lot of requests, so i have to build the html string myself.

In the view i am using the will_paginate helper for the pagination. I really dont know how to build the pagination in a rake task. will_paginate is using stuff like the respond variable.

Can somebody help me to do the pagination without using the request? Or maybe another gem to do the pagination... It doesnt have to look pretty

I am using Rails 2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this through another SO question wanting to preload their cache. https://github.com/tommyh/preheat

```
Preheat.it do
  app.get("/")
end
```

So in your case, you could use a cron job to pre-heat your cache. something like

```
total_user_pages = 9000 #calculate it
Preheat.it do
  1.upto(total_user_pages) do |i| 
    app.get("/users?page=#{i}") 
  end
end
```

I checked and Rails.cache was introduced in 2.1, so you're good there. This gem, unlike mechanize, will not call your webserver

> "ActiveSupport’s fetch method is being
>   modified only in the ruby process
>   which is using Preheat, so something
>   like mechanize/wget/curl would call
>   the page through your frontend
>   webserver and would not be effected by
>   Preheat.it, while app.get will
>   directly call your controller in that
>   same ruby process."

You would then need to use Rails.cache in your app to take advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A nice gem indeed! But not perfect for my situation. app.get does call your application stack i think... I have the normal logs in development.log It is also not that fast.  Benchmark.realtime{10.times{app.get('/')}}
=> 2.60603094100952

Comment: I would try it out -- all calls will need to touch your application stack. The reason I like this is it won't touch your web server, it'll do all the processing in your ruby process.